# How to compare invalid input for a menu

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, irvine32

I have a problem in `getcombo` function. I want to check if the value entered by the user is within the menu option range (1-4). So I compare the value entered by the user with integer values such as 1, 2, 3 and 4 with an `if else` statement. But even when the user enter correct value the programm still ask the user to enter the value again.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

MAX = 80                    
userInput BYTE MAX+1 DUP (?)

msgName BYTE 'Enter Your Name : ' ,0
msgPass BYTE 'Enter Your Password : ' , 0

comboTitle BYTE'COMBO Meals',0
line1 BYTE'==================',0
line2 BYTE'==================',0

comboMeal1 BYTE '1) Chicken Burger      + Coca Cola    + Cheesy Wedges   | RM 15.00',0
comboMeal2 BYTE '2) Grilled Beef Burger + Pepsi        + French Fries    | RM 17.00',0
comboMeal3 BYTE '3) Spicy Korean Wings  + Coca Cola    + salad           | RM 10.00',0
comboMeal4 BYTE '4) Chicken Pizza       + mountain dew + minched Potato  | RM 20.00',0

selectedCombo BYTE ' ',0


prompt1 BYTE 'Please select a Combo Meal : ',0

mealPrice1 dword 15.00
mealPrice2 dword 17.00
mealPrice3 dword 10.00
mealPrice4 dword 20.00

invalidLogin BYTE 'Invalid' , 0
invalidSelection BYTE'Please select within given menu option',0
validPass BYTE 'Valid Password' , 0

loginPassword BYTE "123" , 0
loginName BYTE "bob" , 0


.code
main PROC

Login :

    ;---------------- Display "Enter Your Name"
    mov edx,OFFSET msgName  
        call WriteString
    ;---------------- Get name input 
    call GetInput
    ;---------------- compare user input and name
    mov ebx , OFFSET loginName
    .IF eax == [ebx] 
    ;--------------- Correct input

        ;---------------- Display "Enter Your Password"
        mov edx,OFFSET msgPass  
        call WriteString
        ;---------------- Get password input 
        call GetInput
        ;--------------- compare user input and password
        mov ebx , OFFSET loginPassword
        .IF eax == [ebx] 
        ;--------------Correct input
        jmp displayMenu
        .ELSE 
        ;--------------- Incorrect input
        jmp InvalidInput
        .ENDIF

    ;---------------
    .ELSE 
    ;-------------- Incorrect input
        jmp InvalidInput
    .ENDIF


InvalidInput :
    ;---------------Display "Invalid"
    mov edx,OFFSET invalidLogin  
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    ;--------------- Repeat process
    jmp Login

invalidMenuSelect:
  xor edx,edx
  mov edx, OFFSET invalidSelection
  call WriteString
  call Crlf

  jmp getCombo

display:
    mov edx,OFFSET validPass  
    call WriteString

displayMenu :
   mov edx,OFFSET line1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    xor edx,edx

    mov edx,OFFSET comboTitle
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    xor edx,edx

    mov edx,OFFSET line1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    xor edx,edx

    mov edx,OFFSET comboMeal1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    xor edx,edx

    mov edx,OFFSET comboMeal2
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    xor edx,edx

    mov edx,OFFSET comboMeal3
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    xor edx,edx

    mov edx,OFFSET comboMeal4
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    xor edx,edx

    call Crlf
    mov edx,OFFSET prompt1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    xor edx,edx

    jmp getCombo
    exit

getCombo :
call GetInput

.IF eax == '1' 
xor edx,edx
mov edx, OFFSET comboMeal1
;mov selectedCombo , edx

.ELSEIF eax == '2'
xor edx,edx
mov edx, OFFSET comboMeal2
;mov selectedCombo , edx

.ELSEIF eax == '3'
xor edx,edx
mov edx, OFFSET comboMeal3
;mov selectedCombo , edx

.ELSEIF eax == '4'
xor edx,edx
mov edx, OFFSET comboMeal4
;mov selectedCombo , edx

.ELSE
jmp invalidMenuSelect

.ENDIF
main ENDP



GetInput PROC 
;-------------
;Get User input
;-------------
    xor eax,eax
    mov  edx,OFFSET userInput
    mov  ecx,MAX            
    call ReadString
    mov eax,[edx]
    ret
GetInput ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Your `GetInput` processes 4 bytes of the string not 1.

Comment: This is very far from a [mcve].  It's nowhere near minimal, full of bloated menu-printing code.  You could just put the whole thing in one big string that contains newlines, or you could loop over an array.  (And use the same array for menu selection using an integer index, instead of an if/else chain).  It's also pointless to have two separate `line1` and `line2` with the same contents.  Anyway, use your debugger and check the values of your registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the ReadString function you are using for input is adding the new line feed character to the eax register.  To fix your issue, you can just check `.IF al == '1'` and so on.  A better approach would be to use the Irvine library function `ReadChar` then check the al register.

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOakE.png)

Comment: Please provide code as code, not as screenshots. see [help] and [answer] for details

Comment: thank you. your opinion helped me to resolve my problem.